# Append some items to a div, and the rest to another div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm writing a script to parse a JSON file, and I seem to have got myself into a tricky situation. Can I append half of the returned items in one div element and the other half in another div elemet?

Here is the original markup:

```
<div class="feed"><div class="displayfeed main"></div></div>
<div class="feed"><div class="displayfeed second"></div></div>
```

I want the page to display like this after appending the returned data:

```
<div class="feed">
    <div class="displayfeed main">
        <h3>item1's title</h3>  //Half of the items in "div.main"
        .......
    </div>
</div>

<div class="feed">
    <div class="displayfeed second">
     <h3>item2's title</h3> //Half of the items in "div.second"
     ...........
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: source,
   success: function (data) {
     var item_html = 
        $(data.items).each(function (index, item) {
          '<h3>'+item.title+'</h3>';
        });
      //Any way to append some of them in ('.main') and the rest in ('.second')?
     $('.displayfeed').append(item_html); 
   },
   error: function () {$searcharea.append("<b>No Results Returned</b>");}        
 });
```

I'm looking for any possible suggestions, otherwise I have no choice but to parse the same feed twice. Any help would be appreciated.

Updated:
I've set up a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4XmUu/15/)** using Gogole news feed in JSON format converted by YQL as an example

Comment: Instead of doing this for each item - you could get the length, divide by 2 and iterate over half the items and append them to whichever div you need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiply selector.

```
$.ajax({
   url: source,
   success: function (data) {
      var item_html_main = "";
      var item_html_second = "";
      // assign values to item_html_main and item_html_second variables
      $('.displayfeed.main').append(item_html_main); 
      $('.displayfeed.second').append(item_html_second); 
   },
   error: function () {$searcharea.append("<b>No Results Returned</b>");}        
 });
```

I don't know what structure you have but you can try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: source,
    success: function (data) {
        var item_html_main = "";
        var item_html_second = "";
        // assign values to item_html_main and item_html_second variables
        var count = data.count;
        var half = count/2;
        var counter = 0;
        for(item in data) {
            if(counter < half) {
                item_html_main += item;
            } else {
                item_html_secodn += item;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        $('.displayfeed.main').append(item_html_main); 
        $('.displayfeed.second').append(item_html_second); 
    },
    error: function () {$searcharea.append("<b>No Results Returned</b>");}        
});
```

Comment: I need to use `$(data.items).each(function (index, item)` for each selector, right?

Comment: @user35295 I updated question, but I don't know how to answer this. I just suggested some method.

Comment: @user35295 To provide better help I have to know what data is looks like

Comment: I need your help with your code. I'm not sure how to access the objects in the code. Here's a Google news feed in JSON format [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4XmUu/3/)

Comment: Forgot to include jQuery in the fiddle [Here] is the correct one (http://jsfiddle.net/4XmUu/3/)

Comment: @user35295 but why another answer is accepted if I helped you with your problem and shown you how to parse google news + I was first?

Comment: I accepted your answer first, but then  Bellian came up with a more general approach with the same Google News feed. It works with other feeds that don't have `count` as a field.

Comment: He has same approach as me, but he didn't created count variable. He used items.length - it is Same

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this. if it does not matter which posts is displayed in which container

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<your-URL>",
    success: function (data) {
        var length = 0;
        var items = data.query.results.item;
        items = items.map(function(item){
            return '<h3>'+item.title+'</h3>';
        });
        var half = items.length/2;
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            if(i < half)
                $('.main').append(items[i]);
            else
                $('.second').append(items[i]); 
            length++;
        },

    error: function () {$searcharea.append("<b>No Results Returned</b>");}        
});
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter what item is displayed in which div. I just want some in one div and the rest in another.

Comment: than this should work for you. if the item_html is just a Object with the created titles in it, this should totaly do it.

Comment: I just tested yours. I got error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number ` in this line var length 0;

Comment: sorry i forgot an "=".. shame on me.. and i just copied your `$(data.items).each...` loop dont know the syntax there.

Comment: It isn't working, I'm afraid. I got this error Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor. I've set up a fiddle if you would like to try. **[Link]**(http://jsfiddle.net/4XmUu/11/)

Comment: sry. i thought you know what you were doing with the each thing. http://jsfiddle.net/4XmUu/23/

Comment: you can also specify the output in one place using the array.map function http://jsfiddle.net/4XmUu/24/

Answer (score 1):

Of course, but you need some separator or something

You can append all to your first div and then copy the part you want in the second div out of the first.

Example

item_html

```
<h2>Headline</h2>
<span>
News Text 
</span>
```

js

```
$('.displayfeed').append(item_html); 
sec = $('.displayfeed').find('span').html();
$('.displayfeed').find('span').remove();
$('.displayfeed second').append(sec);
```